# Upload breaks after 3203 Inserts

Tags: mysql

I upload a textfile with approx 30'000 lines into a Mysql-DB.

The upload breaks allways after exactly 3203 lines. A splitted file with less then 3203 lines runs fine. The problem is, for sure, not at line 3203.
Rather in a Mysql-configuration ( for example max_nbrs_of_inserts )

lines looks as follow:

```
...
09.01.92,06:59:27,  34,1322, 31,   2,06:59:27,00:00:00,     16.00,      0.00
...
```

Each of this lines will generate a SQL-INPUT statment as the following example:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO  tmp_GF

(

fldGFDATUMZEIT,

fldNUMMER,

fldRespond,

fldGFP,

fldBesNr,

fldBEGINN,

fldDAUER,

fldVORRAT,

fldVERZEHR,

fldSave,

fldZeig  

)values(

'$GFDATUMZEIT',

$NUMMER,

$Respond,

$GFP,

$BesNr,

'$BEGINN',

'$DAUER',

$VORRAT,

$VERZEHR,

0,

'$Zeig') ";
```

php.ini AND upload-script settings:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 3000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

Ubuntu version 11.10

Mysql version

```
protocol_version    10
version     5.1.58-1ubuntu1
```

Comment: nb) upload breaks without comment

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has its own maximum size for a single request called [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).  This is set to a small amount by default (MySQL's default is 1MB, your distro's may be higher) but can be increased up to 1GB.

Increasing it will not harm performance for existing requests.  The reason it's set small by default is to simply catch what might be mistakes, in case you're not expecting very large packets.

Now, you don't mention a specific error message, but if I have guessed the cause of your problem correctly, MySQL will probably be generating [this error message](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) ("Packet too large" on the server, and "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" or similar on the client).